# Why are text values ending up in wingdings or something similarly useless?

Tags: qgis, text

I have dissolved a layer in QGIS 2.8. The resulting layer has all the column labels and text fields changed to wingdings or something similarly useless. When I look at the layer in ArcGIS, there is no problem and all column labels and text is fine. Any idea what is causing the problem?

Comment: Bad character encoding? QGIS not able to access a font that ArcGIS is, or has some font mapping set (or not set) such that it can't display it?